# AWS Location geocode city by zip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-location-service

In my Java application the user enters their zip code and city to determine the weather in the user's region. If the city is not specified, I need to find it using the entered zip code (the largest city in the state). I use Google geocoding, which is quite expensive.

I'd like to be able to lookup cities information based on an zip code, such as postcode localities in Google Geocoding. Does AWS Location provide this service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Use [Amazon Location's Places API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/places-concepts.html) for your use case, specifically the `SearchPlaceIndexForText` action. With that, you can search for place names, addresses, and business names and get two things in return: geographic coordinates, and address components. Address components is what you need, which gives you things like country, state, city, postal code, etc. You can also store the results if you want to; checkout the `Data storage option` when creating your place index resource.

Here is an example request (using AWS CLI) and response using ZIP codes as the input:

```bash
aws location search-place-index-for-text \
--index-name HerePlace \
--text "98121" \
--filter-countries "USA" \
--max-results 1
```

```json
{
    "Results": [
        {
            "Place": {
                "Country": "USA",
                "Geometry": {
                    "Point": [
                        -122.34468,
                        47.61578
                    ]
                },
                "Interpolated": false,
                "Label": "98121, Seattle, WA, United States",
                "Municipality": "Seattle",
                "PostalCode": "98121",
                "Region": "Washington",
                "SubRegion": "King",
                "TimeZone": {
                    "Name": "America/Los_Angeles",
                    "Offset": -28800
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "Summary": {
        "DataSource": "Here",
        "FilterCountries": [
            "USA"
        ],
        "MaxResults": 1,
        "ResultBBox": [
            -122.34468,
            47.61578,
            -122.34468,
            47.61578
        ],
        "Text": "98121"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to match specifically on zip code. If there was a better match for the entered string than the zip code you could end up with a bogus match. I worked with UK zip codes and the Here backend at least didn't perform 100% as expected. Then again the UK zip codes are composed by two parts separated by a space which might make the parsing harder.