# I want to create a AWS Geo Location service which can be used for converting zip code into Latitude and Longitude values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, maps, cloud, amazon-location-service

I'm pretty new to AWS  Amazon location service. I have an requirement to convert zipcode/text into Geo co-ordinates(Latitude and Longitude values)

I was going through AWS documentation but, I didn't find the right article for this usecase

Here is what I tried so far.

1. Created Map - Esri Light
2. Created Place Index

I'm not sure how I can use these two to convert a provided zipcode into Geo Co-ordinates

After the creation of these two services, it doesn't show up anything further in those resources to take any further action

Hence I'm requesting you to share the steps with me for this configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Location geocode city by zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74598881/aws-location-geocode-city-by-zip)